# Setting path to shared library inside a makefile for execution

Tags: linker, makefile

I want to **run** a program from inside my makefile which is linked against some shared libraries which are of my own creation. But I don't want them to be permanently added to the library pool of my system.

How can I accomplish this?

I already figured that I somehow have to use/set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH but how as this doesn't seem to work for me:

```
run:
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(TESTLIB):$(DEPENDENCIES)
    ./testit
```

Also trying to run an extra export task wasn't successfull:

```
export:
    ldconfig -n $(DEPENDENCIES)
    ldconfig -n $(TESTLIB)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each line in a recipe is run in its own shell, so change it to:

```
run:
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(TESTLIB):$(DEPENDENCIES); \
    ./testit
```

or

```
run:
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(TESTLIB):$(DEPENDENCIES) ./testit
```

Comment: quick and perfect, thank you also for pointing that own shell part out, you kinda enlightened me as I couldn't understand what was going on

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's one of those things that almost everyone using `make` stumbles over at one time or another, and then never forgets anymore.